# Access to props in a React Js without render method

Tags: reactjs

How can I have access to this.props in react but without render method? In a function method with const variable ? When I make console.log(this.props) I get an error.

```
const TopBar = ({ className, ...rest }) => { 
const classes = useStyles(); const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null); const open = Boolean(anchorEl); const [lan ,setLan] = React.useState('EN'); ....
```

where should I place the props ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a functional component you need to pass the props like this

```
const Component = (props) => {

    return <div>Component Content</div>

}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
console.log(props)
```

Comment: I have the following code:

const TopBar = ({ className, ...rest }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const [lan ,setLan] = React.useState('EN'); .... where should I place the props ??

Comment: In this section `({ className, ...rest })` you are destructuring the props, so you can access it like this `console.log(className)` or you can replace `({ className, ...rest })` with '(props)` then you get the full props. hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In a function component, the first argument is the props.

```
const Example = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  return null;
}
```

Comment: I have the following code:

const TopBar = ({ className, ...rest }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const [lan ,setLan] = React.useState('EN'); .... where should I place the props ??

Comment: You already have the props: `({ className, ...rest })`. This code is taking the props and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it into a `className` variable and a `rest` variable.